# Selenium: cannot access Selenium class functions with an object from another class

Tags: c#, selenium

I currently have an issue with my program:

I have 2 classes, both in the same namespace: WindowsFormsApplication2

the first class called **chrome** has all the selenium namespaces

```
using Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
```

and I have created functions in this class

on another hand I have another class called Form1

in this class i can instantiate a chrome object but i am only able to access the functions within the chrome class, in other words :

in form1 , I can do:

```
chrome driver=new chrome("www.yahoo.fr");
driver.gotothispage(); //gotothispage() is a function in chrome class
```

however I am unable to access all the other functions that are in the selenium class from form1 class example:

I cannot do:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).Click();
```

...

I am unable to see the function FindElement()

Is there a way to bypass that.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Hard to answer withour looking at your code. Can you show your implementation?

Comment: No. `FindElement` comes from `OpenQA.Selenium`. So either include it within the namespaces of each file or wrap it up in your `chrome` class. This is entirely what namespaces are for.

Comment: hello, what I am saying is that i can access all the selenium class functions from the chrome class but i cannot access them from the form1 class, I mean that 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).Click();
is working from the chrome class, (findelement exist in the chrome class)

Comment: Yes, and the answer is what I was saying - you will have to include the namespaces within *any* other class you want to use those methods in. This means you'll have to have the namespaces within **both** `form1` and `chrome`.